# Intuition behind between-group covariance matrix from MANOVA?

Tags: covariance-matrix, estimators, manova

Suppose that we have samples from $m$ different $p$-dimensional normal multivariate distributions, where they share a common covariance matrix $\Sigma$ but the mean vectors may be different for each population. That is, the distribution of the populations are $\mathrm{N}_p(\mu_i, \Sigma)$ , for $i = 1,2, \ldots, m.$ Each sample is made up of $n_i$ observations, depending on the group.

So, $\mathbf{y}_{ij}$ is observation $j$ (for $j = 1,\ldots,n_i$) coming from group $i$ (for $i = 1,\ldots,m$). Notice that $\mathbf{y}_{ij}$ is a $p-$dimensional vector that comes from the multivariate normal distribution $\mathrm{N}_p(\mu_i, \Sigma)$.

An estimator for the covariance matrix for all of the data (ignoring the potential difference between groups) is
$$\mathbf{S}=\frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\left(\mathbf{y}_{i j}-\bar{\mathbf{y}}\right)\left(\mathbf{y}_{i j}-\bar{\mathbf{y}}\right)^{\prime} = \dfrac{SS_T}{N-1},$$
where $N= \sum_{i=1}^m n_i$ is the total number of observations and $SS_T$ refers to the total variation (the sum of squares). Now, the total variation $SS_T$ can be broken down into the within-group and between-group variation components:

\begin{align}
\tag{1}
SS_T= & \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\left(\mathbf{y}_{i j}-\bar{\mathbf{y}}_i\right)\left(\mathbf{y}_{i j}-\bar{\mathbf{y}}_i\right)^{\prime}+ \sum_{i=1}^m n_i\left(\bar{\mathbf{y}}_i-\bar{\mathbf{y}}\right)\left(\bar{\mathbf{y}}_i-\bar{\mathbf{y}}\right)^{\prime} =SS_W + SS_B,
\end{align}
where $SS_W$ corresponds to the within-group variation and $SS_B$ to the between-batch variation. From here, a weighted average matrix can be used for the within-group covariance matrix (especially useful if the mean vectors of the distributions are very different):
$$\mathbf{S}_W=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m\left(n_i-1\right) \mathbf{S}_i}{N-m}=\frac{SS_W}{N-m},\tag{2}$$
where $\mathbf{S}_i$ is the covariance matrix estimate from group $i$. This makes sense to me since it's just a weighted average of individual covariance matrices, so it will only model the within-group variation. Similarly, a between-group covariance matrix can be defined as
$$\mathbf{S}_B = \dfrac{SS_B}{m-1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^m n_i\left(\bar{\mathbf{y}}_i-\bar{\mathbf{y}}\right)\left(\bar{\mathbf{y}}_i-\bar{\mathbf{y}}\right)^{\prime}}{m-1}. \tag{3}$$

The formulas make sense to me, at least mathematically. The total variation can be broken down into its between and within-group components as in Equation (1). Intuitively, using the within-group covariance estimator $S_W$ makes sense, since we are averaging individual covariance matrices, and giving a larger weight to groups with more observations. This would be a good estimate for the matrix $\Sigma$.

However, I don't understand the intuition behind Equation (3), because of the term $n_i$. If the term were not there, the expression would look like this:
$$\mathbf{S}_B^* = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^m \left(\bar{\mathbf{y}}_i-\bar{\mathbf{y}}\right)\left(\bar{\mathbf{y}}_i-\bar{\mathbf{y}}\right)^{\prime}}{m-1}. $$
and I could explain it as the covariance matrix of the group means. Thus, the diagonal of  $\mathbf{S}_B^*$ would correspond to the between-group variances for each of the $p$ variables or characteristics being modelled. Adding $n_i$ could be understood as a weighting mechanism (where groups with more observations should be considered more, I understand). But then, what is the intepretation of the resulting matrix $\mathbf{S}_B$? What does each entry tell us? Notice that $\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{S}_W$ have $N$ in their denominator, while $\mathbf{S}_B$ does not. This means that, the bigger the groups $n_i$, the bigger the entries of $\mathbf{S}_B$. If a process has a specific between-group variation, why would making groups bigger affect those values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When considering the computationally efficient forms, let $L$ $(l=1,2,\ldots,L)$ be the number of treatment groups, $\mathbf{B}$ be the variable-by-variable $p \times p$ between-group sum of squares matrix and $\mathbf{W}$ be the $p \times p$ within-group sum of squares matrix [1]. The $jk$th element of these matrices are found as
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
b_{jk}&=\sum_{l=1}^{L}\frac{1}{n_{l}}T_{jl}T_{kl}-\frac{1}{n}G_j G_k\\
w_{jk}&=\sum_{l=1}^{L} \sum_{i=1}^{n_{l}} y_{ijl}y_{ikl} - \sum_{l=1}^{L} \frac{1}{n_{l}}T_{jl}T_{kl},\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $y_{ijl}$ is the $i$th value of variable $j$ in treatment group $l$, $T_{jl}=\sum_i^{n_{l}}y_{ijl}$ is the sum of all values of variable $j$ in group $l$, $G_j= \sum_{l}^{L} T_{jl}$ is the grand total of all observations on variable $j$, and $n=n_1+n_2+ \cdots + n_{L}$.

An equivalent form of the F-test ($H_0: \boldsymbol{\mu}_1=\boldsymbol{\mu}_2= \cdots = \boldsymbol{\mu}_p$) is based, in part, on *Wilk's Lambda* given as
\begin{equation}
\Lambda(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_p) = \frac{|{\bf W}|}{|{\bf B}| + |{\bf W}|} = \prod_{j=1} ^p \left( \frac{1}{1 + \lambda_j} \right),
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_p $ are the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{W}^{-1}\mathbf{B}$  [2].  Although the matrix $\mathbf{W}^{-1}\mathbf{B}$ is square, it is nevertheless non-symmetric such that elements in the upper triangular are not a mirror reflection of elements in the lower triangular.  Since the matrix  $\mathbf{W}^{-1}\mathbf{B}$ is not symmetric, we must resort to using, for example, the *generalized eigenvalue problem*.

The answer to your question about MANOVA and $\mathbf{W}^{-1}\mathbf{B}$ is no different from the $F$-statistic $F=MST/MSE$ for univariate ANOVA (or $F=MSR/MSE$ for regression) -- essentially equal to $\mathbf{B}/\mathbf{W}$. That is, you will obtain a greater $F$ statistic if the between-group variance (based on group means minus the grand mean) exceeds the within-group variance (based on within group residuals -- i.e. noise).  So the diagonal values  $b_{jj}$ are $SST_j$ and diagonal values $w_{jj}$ are $SSE_j$.

Lastly, whenever there's a sample size in the numerator, it denotes a pooled variance, since the vanilla-flavored variance equation is typically scaled by $1/n$.

**References:**

1. D.F. Morrison.  The Multivariate Analysis of Variance, Chap. 5.  In: Multivariate Statistical Methods, 3rd Ed.  New York (NY), McGraw-Hill, 1990.
2. R.A. Johnson, D.W. Wichern.  Comparision of Several Multivariate Means, Chap. 6.  In: Applied Multivariate Statistical Methods, 4th Ed.  Upper Saddle River (NJ), Prenctice-Hall, 1998.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the good answer and references. I understand that the sum of squares matrices  $\mathbf{W}$ and  $\mathbf{B}$ can be used in an F test; and I understand that $n_i$ in the numerator is used for weighting the estimates. However, my lack of understanding is regarding the intuition behind the between-group covariance matrix $\mathbf{S}_B$ that I proposed. Using your notation, $\mathbf{S}_B = \mathbf{B}/(N-K)$. While the diagonal of $\mathbf{B}$ is the "treatments sum of squares for individual response variables", what do the diagonal elements intuitively mean in $\mathbf{S}_B $?

Comment: See updated answer, with a slight change of notation for clarity, and description of what the diagonal elements represent.